# Get audio response from DialogFlow in java

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get the audio response from dialogflow in Spring in byte array and then send the url of the generated file to the front end. I have enabled audio response in dialogflow but I'm not able to understand how to access it using java sdk

Answer (score 0):

After searching found out that the audio feature is only available in the beta feature of gcp ,hence to use it use the following maven dependency-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
<artifactId>proto-google-cloud-dialogflow-v2beta1</artifactId>
<version>0.51.0</version>
```